# Google Map marker disappear after panning or zooming

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I had this Google Maps API working on my burrito blog, but unfortunately the custom markers (I'm using base64 data URL of an svg), stopped working properly, likely after some API update.

They now don't render/be cropped after I do any of the following:

- zooming
- panning so the custom marker is out of view
- sometimes don't initialize at all

I have looked at a bunch of forum posts but none of the solutions seem to work for me. If anyone has some insight that would be great.

The codepen can be found here : https://codepen.io/cjm771/pen/mRdJwr

The main crux of the code is here:

```js
    var dataUrl = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,'+btoa(newData);
                      var contentString = "<div class='map_content'><h5>"+v.title+"</h5><br>"+
                      "<a href='burrito/"+v.cleanUrl+"'>link</a><img class='map-image' src='"+cmcm_url+coverImages[v.coverImage].thumb+"'> Ranking: "+v.ranking+"/10 Burritos</div>";
                      count++;
                        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            map: map,
                            position: results[0].geometry.location,
                            icon: {
                               // size: new google.maps.Size(50,50),
                                scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(50,50),
                                origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
                                url: dataUrl
                               // anchor: new google.maps.Point(16,16),
                            //  map: map
                            },
                            title: v.title,
                            labelClass: "range_none"
                        });
                       

                          marker.addListener('click', function() {
                            // infowindow.close();
                             infowindow.setContent(contentString)
                             infowindow.setPosition(marker.position);
                             infowindow.open(map, marker)
                      });
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: hi geocodezip, thanks for the link. I updated my post. here is the available [codepen](https://codepen.io/cjm771/pen/mRdJwr)